side_effect not iterating on Mock in Pytho
I'm trying to obtain different responses by each call on a Mock by using the side_effect attribute. However, I'm obtaining the first one each time. I would like to ask if I can get any help on it. Thank you in advance
import json
from typing import Dict
from unittest.mock import Mock, patch

import requests


def mock_response_1() -> dict:
    return {"data": {"users": [{"id": "AAA"}]}}


def mock_response_2() -> dict:
    return {"data": {"users": [{"id": "BBB"}]}}


def mock_json_response(mocked_json: Dict, status_code: int = 200) -> Mock:
    response_mock = Mock()
    response_mock.configure_mock(**{
        "return_value.status_code": status_code,
        "return_value.headers": {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
        "return_value.json.return_value": mocked_json,
        "return_value.text.return_value": json.dumps(mocked_json),
    })
    return response_mock()


class ApiClient:
    def get_response(self) -> dict:
        request_r = requests.get(url="https://api.test.com")
        request_r = request_r.json()
        return request_r.get("data")


class MockClient(ApiClient):

    @patch('ApiTest.requests.get')
    def get_response(self, mocked_post: Mock):
        mocked_post.side_effect = iter([
            mock_json_response(mock_response_1()),
            mock_json_response(mock_response_2())
        ])
        return super().get_response()


class TestApiClient:
    client = MockClient()

    def test_get_response(self):
        for i in (0, 1):
            print(f"Iteration {i}: {self.client.get_response()}")

Result:
Iteration 0: {'users': [{'id': 'AAA'}]}
Iteration 1: {'users': [{'id': 'AAA'}]}


Your code the side effect iterator is being reset on each call to get_response(), causing the same response to be returned for both iterations.
Additionally, the get_response() method of MockClient should directly return the mock response without invoking the parent class's method. Adjust the side effect setup to iterate through mock responses correctly, and return the mock response directly from MockClient.
This code will work
File Tree

root/
├── ApiTest/
│   └── api_client.py
└── test_api_client.py

test_api_client.py
import unittest
from ApiTest.api_client import MockClient

class TestApiClient(unittest.TestCase):
    client = MockClient()

    def test_get_response(self):
        for i in range(2):
            print(f"Iteration {i}: {self.client.get_response()}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()

ApiTest\api_client.py
from typing import Dict
from unittest.mock import Mock, patch
import json
import requests

def mock_response_1() -> dict:
    return {"data": {"users": [{"id": "AAA"}]}}

def mock_response_2() -> dict:
    return {"data": {"users": [{"id": "BBB"}]}}

def mock_json_response(mocked_json: Dict, status_code: int = 200) -> Mock:
    response_mock = Mock()
    response_mock.status_code = status_code
    response_mock.headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
    response_mock.json.return_value = mocked_json
    response_mock.text = json.dumps(mocked_json)
    return response_mock

class ApiClient:
    def get_response(self) -> dict:
        request_r = requests.get(url="https://api.test.com")
        request_r = request_r.json()
        return request_r.get("data")

class MockClient(ApiClient):
    def __init__(self):
        self.mock_responses = [
            mock_response_1(),
            mock_response_2()
        ]
        self.response_index = 0

    @patch('requests.get')
    def get_response(self, mocked_get: Mock):
        mocked_get.return_value = mock_json_response(self.mock_responses[self.response_index])
        self.response_index = (self.response_index + 1) % len(self.mock_responses)
        return super().get_response()

Install dependencies
pip install requests unittest

Run it
python test_api_client.py

Iteration 0: {'users': [{'id': 'AAA'}]}
Iteration 1: {'users': [{'id': 'BBB'}]}


